# RavenDB Collection "in" Collection query

Tags: c#, ravendb

I need to preform a query that check if a collection is in given collection, just like the regular in operation but for collections.

```
class Post
{
    public string[] Tags {get;set;}
}


session.Queury<Post>.Where(x=>x.Tags.in(new[]{".net","c#","RavenDB"})).ToList();
```

so if i have in my DB:

```
  new Post{Tags= new[]{"C#",".net"}};
```

it will be returned

but if i have:

```
  new Post{Tags= new[]{"C#",".net","SQLServer"}};
```

it will not be returned.

**Update:**

what i am trying to do is this:

```
  session.Query<Post>()
  .Where(x => x.Tags.All(y => y.In(new[] { "C#", ".net", "RavenDB" })))
  .ToList();
```

but i got System.NotSupportedException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to find a solution:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sessionStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
    {
        RunInMemory = true,
        UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true,
        Conventions =
        {
            DefaultQueryingConsistency = ConsistencyOptions.AlwaysWaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite
        }
    };

    sessionStore.Initialize();

    using (var session = sessionStore.OpenSession())
    {
        var allTags = new[] {"C#", ".net", "RavenDB", "Linux", "Mac"};
        var tagsCollection = new[] {"C#", ".net", "RavenDB"};

        var complementTagsCollection = allTags.Except(tagsCollection).ToList();

        session.Store(new Post
        {
            Tags = new List<string>{"C#",".net"}
        });

        session.SaveChanges();

        // Posts where all their tags are in tagsCollection
        var result = session.Query<Post>().Where(x => !x.Tags.In(complementTagsCollection)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way IN works, it matches ANY of them.
If you want to match all you have to do a separate check for each.